# javascript reassign values to created elements

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in vanilla js and I create a few HTML elements using js. I use a function to create div elements with labels and input inside.

```
function createElements( passengers ){ //passengers is input number 
            var form = document.getElementById("c-form"); //gets an html form 
            for(let i=0;i<passengers;i++){ 
                
                var passenger = document.createElement("div");
                passenger.setAttribute("class" , "p-container");
                var num = document.createElement("h3");
                num.innerHTML = "Passenger : " + (i+1);  //display passenger number 
                passenger.appendChild(num);
                passenger.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                var nameLabel = document.createElement("label"); //create a label 
                var nameSpan = document.createElement("span");
                var t = document.createTextNode("Please enter name : ");
                Namespan.appendChild(t); //append span to plain text 
                var NameInpt = document.createElement("input");
                NameInpt.setAttribute("type" , "text");  //input for name 
                nameLabel.appendChild(nameSpan);
                nameLabel.appendChild(NameInpt);
                passenger.appendChild(nameLabel); //append label to div 
                form.appendChild(passenger); //append div element to html form
            }

        }
```

With the above code, I can create an element like below

[image]

I would like to do the same for a surname without creating more variables and doing the same thing. I am thinking if there is a way I can reassign different values to the variables I already have and I would appreciate your help. I cannot use jquery, this is a uni project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the relevant part of your code (that deals with creating a particular label/input) in a `for` loop, and let that loop over some different label-strings you want to use:

```
function createElements( passengers ) {
    var form = document.getElementById("c-form"); 
    for(let i=0;i<passengers;i++){         
        var passenger = document.createElement("div");
        passenger.setAttribute("class" , "p-container");
        var num = document.createElement("h3");
        num.innerHTML = "Passenger : " + (i+1);
        passenger.appendChild(num);
        
        for (let label of ["first name", "surname"]) {
            passenger.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            var nameLabel = document.createElement("label");
            var nameSpan = document.createElement("span");
            var t = document.createTextNode("Please enter " + label + " : ");
            nameSpan.appendChild(t);
            var NameInpt = document.createElement("input");
            NameInpt.setAttribute("type" , "text"); 
            nameLabel.appendChild(nameSpan);
            nameLabel.appendChild(NameInpt);
            passenger.appendChild(nameLabel);
        }
        form.appendChild(passenger);
    }
}
```